# Error on value's length validation on submit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, oop, dom

OMG, what a novice learner am I! Only the **logical operator is wrong**. (it should be `||` instead of `&&`).

Thank you very, very much.

---

I am having a problem with my DOM HTML project.

I am trying to make a Name text input that its length should be within 2-36 characters. If the users hit submit and the condition is not met, it would display an `alert()` at the top of the page saying that they should input from 2-36 characters. However, the `addEventLisenter()` could not validate the user's input correctly.

**I am not allowed to use HTML5 validators so `minlength` and `maxlength` could not be used inline with `<input>` tag**

Here is my code:

```js
var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value.length;

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (firstName < 2 && firstName > 30) {
    alert("Please input 2-36 characters");
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="firstNameDiv">
    <label class="required" for="firstName">First Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="2-36 characters only" required>
  </div>

  <div class="submitDiv">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/zodiac1710/gLu6398h/2/

Comment: You need to get the length in the event listener, not when the page is first loaded.

Comment: What do you mean by _get the length in the event listener_ ? when the page is loaded, I declare a ```var``` for the ```value.length```. With ```adddEventListener("click", function ()....)}.``` it means to run the function whenever the button is click.
Can you give a hint code for that?

Comment: Didn't you read the answer that's posted below?

Comment: Note also that `firstName>30` will not match your alert/placeholder of **36**

Answer (score 2):

Change your JS to:

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value.length;
  if (firstName < 2 || firstName > 30) {
    alert("Please input 2-36 characters");
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Any code outside the anonymous function you attach to the event is run once, when the code loads. Since the input is likely empty at that time, `firstname` will always be 0.

Also consider looking into ES6 features like `const`, `let` and arrow functions.

Another mistake was to use an `&&` instead of `||` in the condition. You say you want to `alert` if it's shorter than 2 **and** longer than 30. Instead it should be **or**. Thanks to [@Rob Moll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8801599/rob-moll) for pointing that out.

Finally you need to `preventDefault` to make sure the browser does not actually send the data.

Comment: `if (firstName < 2 && firstName > 30)` This will never return true.

Comment: You are right, that's another error

Comment: Thank you, guys. Since I have conditioned the ```value.length``` with operators, I expect it would examine the ```value``` but no. How could I change the condition?

Comment: @TienDang I have updated my answer code, did you do that? If it still doesn't work, please update the code in your question.

Comment: @TienDang And I'm not sure what exactly you mean with "conditioned with operators", but the length of a string is a property like another, so when you set `firstname` it holds a number (the current length), not a reference to the value's length.

Comment: +1 for `event.preventDefault()` within the `if`. Clever way to short-circuit the submit when validation fails.